# Update Attributes User Rank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

Good Morning All,

I have an issues with my rank update and scratching my head as when the criteria is met it updates my user rank to "true" ?

Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/FrostDuke/7552206

Tried to figure this out with Pry but no such luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `user_rank` function updates the user's `rank`, and returns `true` because `update_attributes` succeeded. You then set `user.rank` to that returned `true` in `update_user_rank`.

Either change `user_rank` to return the new rank instead of calling `update_attributes`; or just call `user.user_rank` from `update_user_rank`, without assigning its return value into `user.rank`. I'd suggest the former - change `user_rank` to the following:

```
def user_rank

  sn = self.snippets.where(:approved => true)

  if sn.count >= 10     
    "Author"     
  elsif sn.count > 10 && sn.count >= 20     
    "Co-Editor"     
  elsif sn.count >20 && sn.count >= 100     
    "Chief Editor"     
  else     
    "Clerk"     
  end     
end
```